# Query on Cosmos with Mongo API - LookUp operation

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, lookup, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

Could you let me know how cosmos handles RU & request charge when we use lookup that spans across two collections as shown in the query below. Both collections have shard keys. From metrics we see that there is no request charge on Inventory collection.

```
Product.aggregate([{
$match: {
mpId: 11
}
},
{
  $lookup: {
  from: "Inventory",
  localField: "product.productId",
  foreignField: " productId ",
  as: "product.inventory"
}
}
}])
```

Also this link mentions that lookup performs a left outer join to an unsharded collection but we are using sharded collection. Does this impact the lookup operation and performance.

Thanks & Regards,
Sahana